# Que significa "empurrar o problema com a barriga"?

Tags: significado, expressões

No outro dia ouvi a expressão "empurrar o problema com a barriga".

Qual o seu verdadeiro significado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Empurrar com a barriga" é uma expressão popular que significa *adiar*, *protelar*, ou *ignorar* um problema até que não seja mais possível fazê-lo.

exemplo: "Não dá mais para ficar empurrando com a barriga. Você tem que tomar uma decisão: ou pede um empréstimo no banco e paga as contas, ou fecha a loja."

> - Significado de [Empurrar com a barriga](https://www.dicio.com.br/empurrar-com-a-barriga/#:%7E:text=Significado%20de%20Empurrar%20com%20a,pra%20empurrar%20com%20a%20barriga.) -
>   Deixar para depois algo que precisa ser feito, protelar uma ação ou decisão importante; postergar, adiar: até agora deu pra ir adiando a decisão, mas chegou num ponto que não dá mais pra empurrar com a barriga.